Why is my Node.js code not reaching the unreachable part after processing events with for-await-of loop on EventEmitter?
import { on, EventEmitter } from 'node:events';
import process from 'node:process';

const ee = new EventEmitter();
// Emit later on
process.nextTick(() => {
  ee.emit('foo', 'bar');
  ee.emit('foo', 42);
});

for await (const event of on(ee, 'foo')) {
  // The execution of this inner block is synchronous and it
  // processes one event at a time (even with await). Do not use
  // if concurrent execution is required.
  console.log(event); // prints ['bar'] [42]
}

// Unreachable here
console.log('Unreachable here');


i was expecting 'Unreachable here' to be logged as well, but it didn't,
What could be causing the script to exit prematurely after the for await...of loop completes? How can I modify this code to ensure that 'Unreachable here' is logged after the event processing completes?

Not an expert with Node events but I would have expected the loop to essentially be infinte preventing execution of any other code folowing the for await loop

The code you have here is very similar to the example in the documentation with some subtle differences but the example includes the // unreachable here comment so why would you expect unreachable code to be reachable?

As far as I know await waits for a Promise to be fulfilled. 
Since you await on() you never fulfill such Promise and wait forever.

You could try an async approach like this instead of the for loop:
    ee.on('foo', (value) => {
      console.log(value);
    });

With that your Code can run through and each event will trigger the code inside the callback function.

Did you reach the console.log(event);? I asume you did since you only mentioned not reaching the end of the code. If you didn't however your condition might never be true. In that case check if the await happens before the actual ee const is defined.
if you do reach that code maybe the loop is infinit. And becouse await lets the code wait for the function to be executed it never continues. I hope this was somewhat helpfull.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
